# Чем отличается beacon технология от обычного ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, xmlhttprequest

На крупных сайтах часто видел в кодах ответа понятие"js beacon". А в интернете толком про это ничего не написано, разве что это подобие ajax. Что это вообще такое beacon, технология или что и чем отличается от обычного javascript? Если можно, простыми словами.

Comment: Уведомлялки сервера о чём-либо.

Comment: А можно подробнее, как это работает и чем отличается от стандартного ajax?

Comment: Подробнее тут: https://w3c.github.io/beacon/

Comment: Так там все на английском. А вы сами не знаете?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Запрос делается асинхронно, но без привязки к текущей странице. Например, если вы на­ча­ли такой запрос, а пользователь закрыл вкладку или перешел на другую страницу, то, в отличии обычного AJAX запроса, ваш запрос не бу­дет прерван, и пользователя не нужно будет заставлять ждать его окончания.
2. В отличии от обычного AJAX, вы не получите ответа на такой запроса. Всё, что вы знаете, это то, что запрос поставлен в очередь на отправку на сервер, или нет.

Этот вид запросов идеально подходит для отправки какой-то аналитики при уходе со стра­ни­цы. Например, вы можете записывать сколько времени был пользователь на странице, что делал, и так далее.

```
window.addEventListener('unload', function () {
  navigator.sendBeacon("/log", analyticsData);
}, false);
```

Наверняка можно придумать способ использовать эти запросы для чего-то ещё, но так как вы не можете знать, завершился такой запрос с ошибкой или прошел успешно, вы будете сильно ограничены. Для получения новых данных с сервера такие запросы не подходят.

Наконец, [вы не можете пользоваться этими запросами в IE и Safari](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon#Browser_compatibility). Они там не работают. Значит для ничего, кроме как для не являющейся критически важной аналитики, этот вид запросов пока не подходит.

Comment: Не совсем понял. Например, хочу чтобы новостной блок обновлялся по технологии beacon. Ну пользователь закрыл вкладку и что дальше, в чем смысл, куда будет отправлен ответ, если вкладка закрыта? Или с помощью него можно только отследить, сколько времени была открыта вкладка и что пользователь делал с блоком новостей?

Comment: Только отследить. Блок какой-то обновить не получится. Вы ведь не получаете ответа сервера на такие запросы.